# OData doesn't return context and count after upgrading to .NET 6

Tags: .net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I used .NET 3.1 until I decided to upgrade my app to .NET 6. I did it successfully but some of my modules broke, one of them is OData. I used OData and I got @odata.context, @odata.count and value returned back in 3.1. Now in .NET 6, I get only the value which means that @odata.context and @odata.count aren't present in the return object. In order to make it run, I added this line in my code
`services.AddControllers().AddOData(options => options.AddRouteComponents("v1", GetEdmModel()).Select().Filter().OrderBy());` in my `Startup.cs` where

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Project>("Project");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

My endpoint is as

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 20)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsync()
{
    var projects = await _projectRepository.GetAllAsync();
    return Ok(projects);
}
```

Do you know what can I change and how should I change it in order to get the context and count from OData in .NET 6? I use the usual OData library with 8.0.0 version

EDIT to add more info about @Tiny Wang's answer:
This seems to be working and thank you very much for it! However, I stumbled upon another problem. I tried your example and the working version was on `https://localhost:44327/odata/project$count=true&$skip=0&$orderby=CreateDate%20desc`. My api prefix is `api/[ControllerName]` and I changed

```
options => options.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()).Select().Filter().OrderBy()
```

to

```
options => options.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents("api", GetEdmModel()).Select().Filter().OrderBy()
```

but when I access the endpoint, I get the following error:

> "The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:  MyApp.Api.Controllers.ProjectController.GetAsync (MyApp.Api) MyApp.Api.Controllers.ProjectController.GetAsync (MyApp.Api)"

even tho `GetAsync()` is defined only once. Do you know how can I fix this and what causes it?

Comment: OData works the same in .NET 6 as it did in .NET 5. Which means with a few quirks. `$count=true` hasn't changed. On the other hand, unless `GetAllAsync()` doesn't get all records but returns an IQueryble, you have a serious bug that loads an entire table in memory. That action should return an `IQueryable<>` anyway

Comment: BTW the change isn't in .NET 6 but the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8 library. You can use that library in .NET 5 and still encounter the same problems

Comment: `GetAllAsync()` returns all records as `IEnumerable`. Should I consider this as a bug?

Comment: Yes. Your method loads the entire table in memory and only then applies OData filtering and paging operators. If you used a DbContext and  returned an IQueryable instead, the OData operators would be used to generate the SQL statement itself and only load what's needed. A DbContext is already a multi-entity repository

Comment: Do you think that changing from `IEnumerable` to `DbContext` could fix my errors or this is just an optimization advice? Thank you by the way for the info, didn't know this. :). I added more details tho, I made it work by @Tiny Wang's answer but I have another error now

Comment: IQueryable, not DbContext. Use DbContext directly instead of the non-repository class. A DbContext is already a multi-entity Repository, it doesn't need to be wrapped in another, single-entity one. That's actually a bad design

Comment: My own OData actions are single lines like `[EnableQuery] public IQueryable<Customer> Get()=>_context.Customers.AsNoTracking();` in a controller inheriting from ODataController. You need to enable the Count operation in `AddOData` in your Program.cs or Startup.cs, it's not on by default. And yes, you *do* need to include `$count=true`. That's a very expensive operation that shouldn't execute by default

Comment: Any break sir?@anthino12

Comment: I managed to solve it @TinyWang. Thank you all for the help

Comment: sure, that's good. and if you have a good solution, you can also post it and mark it as the answer. @anthino12

Answer (score 3):

The change was in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData package, not .NET 6. You can use that package in .NET 5 if you want.

First of all, you always had to specify `$count=true`. That's an expensive operation. In a paging query it meant you had to execute *two* queries, one to receive a single page of data and another to count all possible results.

To do that you have to *enable* counting, just like any other OData operation, in the `AddOData()` call that adds the OData middleware.

Finally, for this to have any real effect, the controller action should return an IQueryable that will be used to construct the final LINQ and by extension SQL query. Otherwise your code will load everything in memory. You'd load a 100K row table in memory only to return 10 rows

OData failed to gain traction because it allowed clients to execute inefficient and unoptimized queries. Service developers had no idea what to optimize because client developers were free to execute anything. In later versions of the protocol, all query capabilites are off by default and have to be explicitly enabled. Server developers now can restrict the maximum size, whether expensive sort operations are allowed etc. They can prevent client code from filtering or sorting by unindexed fields for example.

In my own application I add the OData middleware with :

```
var edmModel=ODataModels.GetEdmModel();
services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddOData(opt => opt.Select()
                            .OrderBy()
                            .Filter()
                            .Count()
                            .Expand()
                            .SetMaxTop(250)
                            .AddRouteComponents("odata", edmModel)
            );
```

This enables `Count` and sets the maximum result size to a fairly large 250 - I have some grids users tend to scroll through.

To use the OData endpoints, a Controller that inherits from `ODataController` is needed. Query methods should return an `IQueryable`. If that `IQueryable` comes from a DbContet, the OData query will be used to construct a LINQ query and by extension the final SQL query. This will ensure that only the necessary data will be loaded.

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Customers> Get()
    {
        return _db.Customers.AsNoTracking();
    }
```

An OData controller that works on top of EF Core could look like this :

```
public class CustomersController:ODataController
{
    private readonly ILogger<CustomersController> _logger;
    private readonly SalesContext _db;


    public CustomersController(SalesContext db, ILogger<CustomersController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _db = db;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Customers> Get()
    {
        return _db.Customers.AsNoTracking();
    }
    
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(long key)
    {
        var cust = _db.Customers
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == key);
        if (cust == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Not found: Customer ID = {key}");
        }

        return Ok(cust);
    }
```

...

The `Get(key)` action is necessary to allow retrieving items by ID in OData eg using `customers(123)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried this and this works. However, it works on an endpoint with prefix `odata/project`. My original prefix is `api/project`. I changed `AddRouteComponents("odata", edmModel)` to `AddRouteComponents("api", edmModel)` but I got the following error:
`"The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: MyApp.Api.Controllers.ProjectController.GetAsync (MyApp.Api) MyApp.Api.Controllers.ProjectController.GetAsync (MyApp.Api)"`
Should I make another controller ONLY for `OData` endpoints or is there a way to make this work in an `api/` controller?

Comment: `api` is the default prefix used by Web API controllers. You've mapped both the OData and API middleware to the same endpoint, so the same controller appears twice under the same endpoint, once for each middleware. ASP.NET Core can't decide which one to use. This matters because different filters are applied by each middleware. Web API doesn't recognize `EnableQuery` and would try to map the OData operators to parameters and fail. OData on the other had would generate a LINQ query out of them

Comment: Should I make another controller for `odata/` calls?

Comment: You should use a different prefix. Why are you changing `odata` to `api` ?

Comment: So my calls go to api/project and not odata/project. api/project doesn't return @odata.count.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

==================================

Per my test(created a .net 6 web api project and install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.10`), I need to add `?$count=true` behind my url then it can appear in my response.

My program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options => options.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()).Select().Filter().OrderBy());

IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast>("Hello");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

My test controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Controllers;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("odata/[Controller]")]
    public class HelloController : ODataController
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        [EnableQuery]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Id = index,
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This made it work but I can access it only on `odata/project?$count...`, even tho my prefix is `api/project..`. I tried changing `AddRouteComponents("odata"..)` to `AddRouteComponents("api"..)` but I get a different error this time. I added more info in the original post. Thank you for this though

Comment: please note my `[Route("odata/[Controller]")]` in my controller, I think you can change it to `[Route("api/[Controller]")]`, take a try? @anthino12 thank you

Comment: Changed it but still doesn't work. I think that the prefix is taken from `AddRouteComponents`. Thank you for your help

Comment: both change `[Route("api/[Controller]")]` and in the Program.cs `AddRouteComponents`