# Odata $count and Search by Entity Id Not Working in Dot Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata

Odata Count is not supporting, not sure what is missing.

```
 https://localhost:7080/odata/Person?$count
 Microsoft.OData.ODataException: The value for OData query '$count' cannot be empty.
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ThrowIfEmpty(String queryValue, String queryName)

  https://localhost:7080/odata/Person?$count=true
  Status Code 200 but count is not displayed.
```

I have referred [this issue](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/247) and came to know others have faced this issue before too then here as well [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256681/odata-doesnt-return-context-and-count-after-upgrading-to-net-6).

Using  Packages

```
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.0.10"
  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version="6.0.0"
```

Controller

```
[Route("odata/[controller]")]
public class PersonController : ODataController
{
    private readonly IPersonRepo _repo;
    public PersonController(IPersonRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 5)]
    //[HttpGet("Person/$count")]
    //[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        return _repo.Get();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new();
builder.EntitySet<Person>("Persons");
return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
     builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options => options
    .AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel())
    .Select()
    .Filter()
    .OrderBy()
    .SetMaxTop(20)
    .Count()
    .Expand()
     );
```

Comment: Could you please share your entity model? In addition, have you checked that the data you are quering has record?

Comment: Along with `IQueryable` have you tried `AsNoTracking`? Could you please confirm?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron 
Model

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    
}

Comment: public IQueryable<Person> Get()
{
    return _context.Pesons.AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();
}

Comment: The value for OData query '$count' cannot be empty. Same error I am getting.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes there is data from DB.

Comment: alright, thanks for our reply along with the information.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron have you faced this issue or can you identity what is missing from my code.

Comment: Well, I was investigating it though, have you tried that by setting count param as true like this `$count=true`?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Its a known issue https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2096 but when I try thier steps it does not work.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Also
localhost:7080/odata/Person(1) //1 is the PK on table and Key on Entity this also does not work ,filter, select, top, skip is working.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron $count=true returns the same response as localhost:7080/odata/Person but with out count in it. Thanks for investigation. Am stuck on this since 2 days.

Comment: I got your concern. However, do you have any other .NET version? Does count is working there? Could you please try that out?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes other version its working. Its fixed now
builder.EntitySet<Person>("Persons");
Here Persons is called and controller name is PersonController that was the issue. Thank you.